# While iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator

I'm experiencing an anomaly in java that i can't wrap my head around.

In my main class i have the following code:

```
(import java.util.*;)
...

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String name;
int i = 1;

System.out.println("How many names do you want to enter?");
int iteratorCount = input.nextInt();
iteratorCount++;

  while (i < iteratorCount){
  System.out.println("Ener name number "+i);
  name = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println(name);
  i++;
  }
```

But during the first itiration of the while loop i don't get asked to write a name. The text "Enter name number 1" does appear however. This is the output:

```
How many names do you want to enter?
>>5
Ener name number 1

Ener name number 2
>>Jack
Jack
Ener name number 3
>>John
John
Ener name number 4
>>Lisa
Lisa
Ener name number 5
>>Paul
Paul
```

where `>>` is user entered text.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) **doesn't** consume the `'\n'` character (the enter key you hit after you insert an `int`), scenario:

```
>>> How many names do you want to enter?
>>> 5 (and hit enter)
>>> Enter name number 
>>> \n (consumed)
>>>
```

Solutions:

- put another `nextLine` right after `nextInt` in order to consume that character instead
- (not recommended but might help you to understand your problem) have another `Scanner` instance